# Paper.js shim config Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, paperjs

I'm trying to initialize an application but seem to be having trouble getting paper js to properly load into my script. I'm using require.js as my AMD loader and am trying to load paper js with the shim module.

Here's my code:

```
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),//used to keep the browser from caching the scripts as we move
    baseUrl : "scripts",//base scripts page!
    paths : {   
        'jquery' : "../components/jquery/jquery.min", //specific libraries -- can be specified later
        'underscore' : "../components/underscore/underscore",
        'paper' : "../components/paper/paper"
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'paper' : {
            exports: 'Paper'
        },
    },
});

// initialize the document with a doc ready!

requirejs(["jquery", "underscore", "paper"], function ($, _, Paper) {
    alert(_);
    alert(Paper);
});
```

The first alert works fine, (the underscore) meaning that it loads okay, but I can't seem to figure out how to get paper.js working properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First step: check your javascript console to ensure that components/paper/paper is getting loaded.

Comment: After snooping in the library, shouldn't it be 'PaperScript' instead of 'Paper'?

Comment: hey, it looks like everything was loading, but i needed to wrap it in a define module

Comment: something like this: define(function() { return paper; }); I actually tweeted the librarie's creator and he said it exported the "paper" var so that's all i need to introduce into my module scope

Comment: You don't need to do the define, that's the purpose of SHIM. Shim inspects the globals for to automatically apply to your modules.

Comment: I actually checked again and using paper as the export variable seemed to work with a newer copy of the library. I think I may have been using a bad download (as I was hacking around in the lib-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PaperJS global namespace is "paper".

Simply replace "Paper" by "paper" and it should work.

```
'paper' : {
    exports: 'paper'
}
```

Comment: worked great, I did this about a week ago! The two libraries work quite nicely together.